# Cannot successfully login with Facebook in Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, facebook-login

The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook: {"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"AzfZT6nJx2NshSwvPrmdgZd"}} ]

This is the error I receive in the console. What should I do to log in successfully with Facebook?

````dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:flutter_login_facebook/flutter_login_facebook.dart';

abstract class AuthBase {
  User get currentUser;
  Stream<User> authStateChanges();
  Future<User> signInAnonymously();
  Future<User> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
  Future<User> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
  Future<User> signInWithGoogle();
  Future<User> signInWithFacebook();
  Future<void> signOut();
}

class Auth implements AuthBase {
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  @override
  Stream<User> authStateChanges() => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();

  @override
  User get currentUser => _firebaseAuth.currentUser;

  @override
  Future<User> signInAnonymously() async {
    final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
    return userCredential.user;
  }

  @override
  Future<User> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
      EmailAuthProvider.credential(email: email, password: password),
    );
    return userCredential.user;
  }

  @override
  Future<User> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
    final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
    return userCredential.user;
  }

  @override
  Future<User> signInWithGoogle() async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (googleUser != null) {
      final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
      if (googleAuth.idToken != null) {
        final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth
            .signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
          accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        ));
        return userCredential.user;
      } else {
        throw FirebaseAuthException(
          code: 'ERROR_MESSAGE_ID_TOKEN',
          message: 'Missing Google ID Token',
        );
      }
    } else {
      throw FirebaseAuthException(
        code: 'ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER',
        message: 'Sign in aborted by user',
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<User> signInWithFacebook() async {
    final fb = FacebookLogin();
    final response = await fb.logIn(permissions: [
      FacebookPermission.publicProfile,
      FacebookPermission.email,
    ]);

    switch (response.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.Success:
        final accessToken = response.accessToken;
        final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
          FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken.token),
        );
        return userCredential.user;

      case FacebookLoginStatus.Cancel:
        throw FirebaseAuthException(
          code: 'ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER',
          message: 'Sign in aborted by user',
        );
      case FacebookLoginStatus.Error:
        throw FirebaseAuthException(
          code: 'ERROR_FACEBOOK_LOGIN_FAILED',
          message: response.error.developerMessage,
        );
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
    final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
    await facebookLogin.logOut();
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}```
````

Comment: add you code what are you trying

Comment: How will it navigate to my homepage as it does with other methods-Google, Email, Anonymous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For error code 190, first thing you'd want to check is that if you have enabled facebook as a sign in method in your firebase console.
Go to your firebase and go in to firebase auth and in that enable facebook auth then go to rules and double check that you have permission to read and write. Then go over to your Facebook developer console and make sure you added your app bundle ID and everything there is okay as per the documentation. You problem is caused by invalid OAuth credentials, meaning either facebook console or firebase console are ill-configured.

Update on what happens after starting with these suggestions.

Comment: Now I have another issue -The app allows the user to sign in using Facebook, but I am having trouble with when the user wants to use a different Facebook account to sign in, this page will only show the continue button. Is there a way for the user to choose to use a different account for signing in?@Huthaifa Muayyad

Comment: Hello again, can you post your question to a new post and tag me there I would gladly try to assist you. Please share the code you are using to invoke the signin flow.